# get and remove the object in nsmutablearray at specific index

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want the name of method of nsmutablearray which return the object at the given index and then remove this object from index and then sort the array accordingly.

Comment: Any reason why you don't look at the reference docs for `NSMutableArray` and `NSArray`. That's the best place to find out what methods are available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're looking for two different things. To retrieve the object at a specific index in an array, you use `-[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]`. To remove an object at a specific index you use `-[NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:]`.